# How do you abstract generics in nested Rust types?

Tags: generics, nested, rust, traits

```
struct Disk<T: Read + Seek + Write> {
    handle: T,
}

struct Partition<T: Read + Seek + Write> {
    disk: Disk<T>,
}

struct File<T: Read + Seek + Write> {
    partition: Partition<T>,
}
```

At the point of `struct Partition`, it is no longer interesting what `Disk`s trait-bounds are. Through the language design, it is not possible to create a `Disk` with a handle what does not have `Read + Seek + Write`. Through this example is very simple, types might become extremely complex if they have multiple members with traits.

What I want is:

```
struct Disk<T: Read + Seek + Write> {
    handle: T,
}

type ExDisk = FIXME;

struct Partition {
    disk: ExDisk,
}

struct File {
    partition: Partition,
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do you abstract generics in nested types?

Rust does abstractions by traits; so use a trait (not a type).

Specifically, `Partition` should depend on a generic parameter implementing a trait rather than on `Disk<T: ...>` itself.

```
trait Volume {}

struct Disk<T: Read + Seek + Write> {
    handle: T,
}

impl<T: Read + Seek + Write> Volume for Disk<T> {}

struct Partition<V: Volume> {
    volume: V,
}

struct File<V: Volume> {
    partition: Partition<V>,
}
```

*Alternatively `File` could itself depend on an abstract partition.*

Note that using this `Volume` trait, it is even possible to remove the generic parameter completely; as long as the `Volume` trait is object-safe *and* the object behind does not need to store a local reference:

```
struct Partition {
    volume: Box<Volume>,
}

struct File {
    partition: Partition,
}
```

It adds a tiny bit of over-head (a dynamic allocation + indirect calls), but gives you a single type instead of a family.

---

Another solution to only reduce verbosity is to introduce a new `trait` for specifically this purpose:

```
trait Volume: Read + Seek + Write {}

impl<T> Volume for T where T: Read + Seek + Write {}
```

Allows you to thereafter use the `Volume` trait as a short-hand for the sum of traits it represents. This does not abstract the disk, but is certainly convenient.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question (although it evidently does as OP accepted it). OP wanted to be able to say `struct Partition {`, but this answer still has a generic parameter for `Partition` and `File`.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I read the question as reducing the complexity (and abstracting away the bounds of inner members), not necessarily removing all bounds. Note that if `Volume` is object-safe, it would be possible to have `Partition` contain ` Box<Volume>` and it would be parameter-less.

Comment: I accepted this because it reduces the complexity. Through it is true that using a trait object in a box `Box<Volume>` would answer the question more correctly.

Comment: @eddy: Let me add the variation then, and make it complete. Also, in the future, do not feel pressured to accept an answer right away. An accepted answer is like a "nothing to see here, move along" sign to potential answerers, some might still answers but most will move on to greener pastures. Therefore, I encourage you to only accept answers once they really answer your question, and otherwise wait for a better answer... at least for a few days.